# mysql get real row number

Tags: mysql

i have this table

```
mysql> select name from test;
+---------+
| name    |
+---------+
| foo     |
| bar     |
| foobar  |
| anton   |
| budi    |
| anton S |
+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how to know if first 'anton' is record number 4?

is there any faster query than this...

```
select rank from (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank,p.name from test p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r) a, (select * from test where name like 'anton%' limit 1) b where b.NAME = a.name
```

Comment: Do you not have an `id` column?

Comment: make it in script just multiply $i*offset, thats simple and faster..

Answer (score 4):

No.

There is no such thing as a "row number" in a table; only in an ordering imbued by `ORDER BY` (or possibly `GROUP BY`).

Records in tables have no *inherent* ordering, even though without an `ORDER BY` clause you may often happen to see them presented in insertion order for implementation reasons.

If you want to make use of insertion order, add an auto-incrementing `ID` column and use that.

Answer (score 1):

The only "fast" way to have a "row number" is to add a "row counter" column :)
The problem there is that you have to keep your records up to date when you delete some of them. If there is no DELETE action (or they are very limited) , a column would be an acceptable choice.

Comment: add "row number" column doesn't work when i use 'ORDER BY' to sort the tables.